# Isn't frequentism flawed, at least in the case of small samples?

Tags: bayesian, inference, frequentist

In his talk on [Frequentism and Bayesianism](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KhAUfqhLakw), Jake VanderPlas discusses [Bayes' billiard game](http://halfonlab.ccr.buffalo.edu/Bioinformatics%20Primers%20from%20Nature%20Biotechnology/Eddy_2004_Nat%20Biotechnol-15340486.pdf) (10:57). Jake sketches how frequentists arrive at an odds 0.053 of winning for Bob after three more moves when Alice is 5:3 ahead after eight moves, while Bayesians arrive at 0.091 which is almost twice as high.

Jake charmingly skips the answer who of both is right – but one of them *has* to be right, I guess. To answer the question, I wrote a tiny JavaScript (see below) which unambiguously decided that the **Bayesians are right** – and indeed perfectly right. Bob's odds of winning definitely *are* 0.091.

That seems to imply that the **frequentists are wrong**, at least in the case of small samples. But can this be the case in view of all the predictions and parameter estimations that are made on frequentists' assumptions? And is it really a matter of philosophy (as Jake suggests)? Or isn't it a matter of right and wrong?

---

This is the script:

```
var experiments = 1
var gamesPerExperiment = 10000000
var bobWinsFrequentist = 0

for (var experiment = 0; experiment < experiments; experiment++) {
    var gamesConsidered = 0
    var bobWins = 0
    
    for (var game = 0; game < gamesPerExperiment; game++) {
        var threshold = Math.random()   // draw a random line on the billiard table
        var alice = 0
        var bob = 0
        for (var move = 0; move < 8; move++) {      // eight moves are made
            if (Math.random() > threshold) alice++
            else bob++
        }
        if (alice == 5 && bob == 3) {               // consider only these cases
            gamesConsidered++
            for (var move = 0; move < 3; move++) {  // three more moves are made
                if (Math.random() > threshold) alice++
                else bob++
            }
            if (bob > alice) bobWins++
        }
    }
    
    if (bobWins/gamesConsidered < 0.06) bobWinsFrequentist++
    if (experiments == 1) console.log("Bob's odds = " + bobWins/gamesConsidered)
}

if (experiments > 1) console.log("Bob's odds < 0.06 = " + bobWinsFrequentist/experiments)
```

It outputs almost surely `Bob's odds = 0.091...`. If you run the script with `experiments=1000` and `gamesPerExperiment=1000` you will find that frequentists are possibly right in approx. 10% of the experiments.

Comment: IMO this example is totally contrived, and there are multiple instant no-go's in the setup. First, it isn't clear that the Bayesian and Frequentist solutions must be different because *replicating the experiment can be interpreted as involving re-rolling the ball*. Presumably, the optimal Frequentist decision rule for accepting a bet will end up coinciding with the Bayes solution if we interpret the repeated-sampling in this way. Second, if we assume that replicating the study involves not re-rolling the ball, then of course the Bayesian will do better: he is using a "correct" prior...

Comment: ... and hence is making use of more information than the Frequentist is permitted. Third, there is a presumption that a Frequentist simply *must* reduce their decision to constructing the cutoff from the MLE, but I cannot think of an obvious reason why they are required to do this. My first step would be to derive the minimax decision rule instead; this often will correspond to a Bayes rule under a particular prior (haven't done the math on this). Of course the Bayesian will still win because the deck is stacked in his favor because he is using a correct prior, but this is at least more fair.

Comment: @guy Even with an incorrect uninformative prior, the Bayesian could do well: with a uniform prior you get $\frac1{11} \approx 0.091$ (which is correct if the starting ball is positioned uniformly). Meanwhile a Jeffreys prior would give $\frac7{80} = 0.0875$, a Haldane prior $\frac1{12} \approx 0.083$.

Comment: @Henry Sure, but they won’t be guaranteed to do better than an optimal Frequentist for all priors. Making the crude approximation that all loss functions are equivalent to squared error loss, the minimax rule would correspond to taking a beta prior with both shape parameters equal to $\sqrt 2$ and then using the associated Bayes rule, which will also perform well.

Comment: @guy: I tried to understand what exactly is totally contrived in my (code) example.. I think it describes an experimental setup quite clearly, and it yields "correct" results. Is it possible to point to lines of code that contribute to the contrivedness of the (code) example? Or did you mean Bayes' billiard game for itself is a contrived example?

Comment: The code is fine, the example is contrived.

Answer (score 2):

The reason has to do with the phrasing of the paper and the nature of the problem itself.  By theorem, that result had to happen.

When I was an academic,  I used to do a seminar for the math club on how your choice of axioms determined your solution in the field of probability and statistics.  What you are seeing is the result of axioms conflicting with the nature of the problem.

If you are placing money at risk, then you must use a Bayesian method.  There is no choice on the matter.

The relevant issue is the Dutch Book Theorem and its converse.

In 1930, Bruno de Finetti realized that if you could force a bookie to take a loss due to the rules of probability that you were using, they wouldn’t play the game.  So, using that as the grounding principle, that a bookie won’t play in a game of “heads you win, tails I lose,” he asked what rules of math follow from that.

The result is the Dutch Book Theorem.  Lehman and Kemeney proved the converse, independently, around 1955.  The implication of the converse was that Frequentist methods will not, with a handful of narrow exceptions, produce valid gambling odds.

While it is necessary to use Bayesian methods, it is not sufficient.  In the general case, you cannot use uninformative priors.  You cannot mimic Frequentist methods if you want to gamble.

Each method of solving problems has been designed to be optimal for certain classes of problems but can be very ill-designed for others.  To consider a type of problem where this outcome is reversed, remember President Trump’s obsession with hydroxychloroquine.
Preliminary work on hydroxychloroquine that I saw showed that it was somewhat effective if you looked in a Bayesian framework but not a Frequentist framework.  As evidence mounted, the Frequentist method ended being correct.
In a sense, Frequentist methods are prejudiced in that the null is treated as true.  As it is ill-advised to put deadly chemicals in your body, medicine treats proposed treatments as either producing no effect or being harmful upon administration.  Most Frequentist methods minimize the maximum amount of risk you will be exposed to from getting an unfortunate sample.  Getting an unfortunate initial sample is what happened with hydroxychloroquine.

As the sample size grew, the two methods converged, but based on initial samples, the two methods disagreed.  The Bayesian probabilities were based on the observed data.  The Frequentist probabilities required overwhelming evidence because it was concerned with the entire sample space that could be out there instead of just the observed sample.  That makes the method very conservative.

Even with Frequentist methods, it is inevitable that you will be made a fool of sometimes.  However, by choosing a cutoff probability, usually called $\alpha$, you get to control the maximum frequency with which you will be a fool.

It is better to think of the frequencies obtained under null hypothesis methods as depending on the model you chose and a loss or utility function.

You shouldn’t use Bayesian methods to solve Frequentist problems, generally.  You also shouldn’t use Frequentist methods to solve Bayesian problems, generally.

Comment: Please let me point me to my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

So, I think it is important for these sorts of "gotcha" problems to think clearly about what we are being asked to do. This is my best attempt to distill the problem down to something we can actually analyze

> In repeated samples, what proportion of the time $q$ will Bob win the game when the score is 5-3? Provide an estimate $\widehat q$ of this probability.

In order to answer this question, we need to be explicit about what a "repeated sample" is. There are two natural interpretations:

1. Consider many replications of  the entire experiment: we roll the ball, Alice and Bob play the game, and we find ourselves in the situation where Alice has 5 points and Bob has 3.
2. The exact same, but we don't reroll the ball.

The point is that, in scenario 1, nothing is unknown and the answer is just an application of Bayes theorem. Frequentists are allowed to use Bayes theorem, there is nothing inherently Bayesian about it, and doing anything else would basically just be wrong if you are a Frequentist. **Note that this is the scenario which is dealt with by the simulations.**

So there is no disagreement in scenario 1, and we can assume without loss of generality that we are in scenario 2. In this case, $q = (1 - p)^3$. The Bayesian reports $\widehat q = 1/11$ while the Frequentist reports $(1 - 5/8)^3$ (assuming we use the MLE, which we are not obliged to do, but I'll just note that using MLE is a choice which is orthogonal to Bayes/Frequentist issues). Which one is correct? Well, that *depends on what $p$ is*. If we are addressing this problem from the Frequentist perspective, $p$ is a fixed-but-unknown quantity, and we have fixed this for eternity by stating that a replication of the experiment would not involve re-rolling the ball.

Modeling this experiment would involve taking your threshold outside the loop, and the relative performance of the two methods will now depend on what $p$ you happen to sample.

To be clear, the only way for there to be any disagreement between the two methods is if you are in scenario 2. Scenario 1 is a strawman because, from the Frequentist perspective, there are no unknown parameters - we know exactly what happens under repeated sampling, so there is nothing to estimate. Possibly the confusion is related to the conflation between Bayesian statistics (a theory of uncertainty quantification) and Bayes theorem (a theorem of probability which is applicable to both Frequentist and Bayesian interpretations of probability). The seemingly bad behavior of Frequentist versus Bayes in this example is attributable to the fact that we force the Frequentist to use an estimator from scenario 2 but adopt scenario 1 to judge their answer.

An analogy: it's like asking a Bayesian and a Frequentist to estimate the area of the circle but allowing a Bayesian use $\pi$ while forcing the Frequentist to throw darts to estimate $\pi$, and concluding from the result that Frequentist statistics is bunk because their dart-throwing estimator does a bad job.

Comment: (+1) for this line: _Frequentists are allowed to use Bayes theorem, there is nothing inherently Bayesian about it, and doing anything else would basically just be wrong if you are a Frequentist._ I think this addresses a widespread misconception.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy: What is the misconception? That frequentists **are** allowed to use Bayes theorem etc. or that they were **not**?

Comment: @guy: Please let me point me to my answer below.

Comment: @Hans-PeterStricker I think your answer makes a fair point! More generally, for an arbitrary prior on $p$, we can't know whether the MLE will be closer (on average) to the correct answer than the Bayes estimator - for some priors, the MLE will do better, while for other priors the Uniform prior estimator will do better.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the great answers! I think I've got it, at least partially. If we do the same experiments as above, only using another prior – not the uniform p-distribution, but the delta-distribution $\delta(p-3/8)$ – one can reproduce the frequentists' result:

```
var gamesPerExperiment = 1000000;

var gamesConsidered = 0;
var bobWins = 0;

for (var game = 0; game < gamesPerExperiment; game++) {
    var threshold = 3/8                         // draw the line always at 3/8
    var alice = 0;
    var bob = 0;
    for (var move = 0; move < 8; move++) {      // eight moves are made
        if (Math.random() > threshold) alice++
        else bob++
    }
    if (alice == 5 && bob == 3) {               // consider only these cases
        gamesConsidered++
        for (var move = 0; move < 3; move++) {  // three more moves are made
            if (Math.random() > threshold) alice++
            else bob++
        }
        if (bob > alice) bobWins++
    }
}
console.log("Bob's odds = " + bobWins/gamesConsidered)
```

This outputs almost surely `Bob's odds = 0.0526...`.

Lesson learned: When there is no reason to believe that the uniform p-distribution is more probable than the delta-distribution, Bayesians cannot claim that their result is more correct than the frequentists'.

Comment: "Bayesians cannot claim that their result is more correct than the frequentists." That statement isn't quite accurate. There definitely are cases, due to the nature of the problem, that only one of the two methods is valid.  There are also cases that are not uncommon where only a Bayesian solution exists or only a Frequentist solution exists. For example, for variables with a continuous distribution the hypothesis $\mu=k$ only can have a Frequentist solution. Because parameters are random in Bayesian math, the probability of the hypothesis must have a measure of zero.

Answer (score 1):

The frequentist isn't really "wrong", because they don't hold the false belief that Bob's probability of winning is exactly given by that calculation using the MLE - they believe that the MLE is just a estimate. (Hopefully the frequentist would concede that there's no point in using that estimate here when it's possible to calculate the exact answer using Bayes' Theorem.)

Comment: That means sometimes it's **not** possible to calculate the exact answer using Bayes' theorem but only by the MLE? Can you give a simple example where this is the case?

Comment: When the frequentists believe their number is "just an estimate", what do the Bayesians think and say? "It's just a belief"? Both will concede that they may be wrong. Is there a difference between the frequentists' "wrong" and the Bayesians' "wrong"? And **how** wrong they possibly are?

Comment: To your first comment: as the MLE is just an estimate, it can't be used to exactly calculate the probability of future events. To your second comment: no, the Bayesians can't be wrong - they have correctly calculated the exact probability of Bob winning, something the frequentists never claimed to be able to do without Bayes' Theorem.

Comment: Please let me point me to my answer below.